# Objective C, how to decode this UTF16 string?

Tags: objective-c, unicode, utf-16

I have a string like this,

```
NSString *u = @"%u9ED1%u9AD4";
```

I need to decode this UTF16 string to obtain the unicode entity below:

```
黑體
```

I am trying this:

```
NSData *fontNameData = [@"%u9ED1%u9AD4" dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
   NSString *l = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:fontNameData encoding:NSUTF16StringEncoding];
   NSLog (l);
```

Doesn't seem to work. What am I doing wrong?
Will greatly appreciate the help

Answer (score 2):

Like this:

```
NSString *u = @"%u9ED1%u9AD4";
u = [u stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"%u" withString:@"\\u"];
u = [u stringByApplyingTransform:@"Any-Hex" reverse:YES];
NSLog(@"%@", u); // 黑體
```