# Display Unicode String as Emoji

Tags: ios, objective-c, emoji

I currently receive emojis in a payload in the following format:

```
\\U0001F6A3\\U0000200D\\U00002640\\U0000FE0F
```

which represents "‍♀️"

However, if I try to display this, it only shows the string above (escaped with 1 less ), not the emoji e.g.

```
NSString *emoji = payload[@"emoji"];
NSLog(@"%@", emoji) then displays as \U0001F6A3\U0000200D\U00002640\U0000FE0F
```

It's as if the unicode escape it not being recognised. How can I get the string above to show as an emoji?

*Please assume that the format the data is received in from the server cannot be changed.*

**UPDATE**

I found another way to do it, but I think the answer by Albert posted below is better. I am only posting this for completeness and reference:

```
NSArray *emojiArray = [unicodeString componentsSeparatedByString:@"\\U"];
NSString *transformedString = @"";

for (NSInteger i = 0; i < [emojiArray count]; i++) {

    NSString *code = emojiArray[i];
    if ([code length] == 0) continue;
    NSScanner *hexScan = [NSScanner scannerWithString:code];
    unsigned int hexNum;
    [hexScan scanHexInt:&hexNum];
    UTF32Char inputChar = hexNum;
    NSString *res = [[NSString alloc] initWithBytes:&inputChar length:4 encoding:NSUTF32LittleEndianStringEncoding];
    transformedString = [transformedString stringByAppendingString:res];
}
```

Comment: There is no magic bullet, you will just have to parse by hand. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44664541/how-to-decode-a-utf16-string-into-a-unicode-character for example

Comment: @RunLoop cross check the emoji code, for swift the code is giving not valid

Comment: Could you show how you fill payload?

Comment: How you parse downloaded data?

Comment: Can you show us the raw data for payload?

Comment: @AlbertRenshaw I have updated the question - I am receiving double \\

Comment: @RunLoop Does your program also create the payload? If so is preventing the escaping in the first place a viable solution, or do you have to strictly fix it post-facto?

Comment: @RunLoop Found a way to decade the string, posted as answer below! https://stackoverflow.com/a/60713375/2057171

Comment: Please don’t post a solution as part of the question. Post it as an answer. Answering your own question is fine, and who knows, it might get upvotes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the excess backslash then convert with a reverse string transform `stringByApplyingTransform`. The transform must use key "Any-Hex" for emojis.

```
NSString *payloadString = @"\\U0001F6A3\\U0000200D\\U00002640\\U0000FE0F";
NSString *unescapedPayloadString = [payloadString stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"\\\\" withString:@"\\"];
NSString *transformedString = [unescapedPayloadString stringByApplyingTransform:@"Any-Hex" reverse:YES];

NSLog(@"%@", transformedString);//logs "‍♀️"
```

Comment: Showing that this is a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57103365/objective-c-how-to-decode-this-utf16-string etc. :)

Comment: @matt What a small world, I read your initial comment on this post that it would have to be parsed manually, then I sleuthed for about 50 minutes to finally find that solution, upvoted you there, and just now realize you yourself wrote that solution many months ago haha. I had been working w/ transforms using "Any-Hex/Unicode" to no avail but using just "Any-Hex" was the key

Comment: Actually there are only about six users on Stack Overflow so this was bound to happen. :)

Comment: Thank you @AlbertRenshaw. I also found an alternate solution I posted in my question, though I think yours is better. I tested both on a variety of emojis, especially those with many surrogate pairs, and all works well.

Comment: Damn u beat me to it. I was just about to post this solution.

Answer (score 1):

I investigated this, and it seems you may not be receiving what you say you are receiving. If you see `\U0001F6A3\U0000200D\U00002640\U0000FE0F` in your NSLog, chances are you are actually receiving `\\U0001F6A3\\U0000200D\\U00002640\\U0000FE0F` at your end instead. I tried using a variable

```
NSString *toDecode = @"\U0001F6A3\U0000200D\U00002640\U0000FE0F";
self.tv.text = toDecode;
```

And in textview it is displaying the emoji fine.
[image]

So you got to fix that first and then it will display well.

Comment: Thanks, I am indeed receiving double \\ as you pointed out, but I can't seem to replace \\ with \.